# Don't request offline access with the google api ruby client

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using the [google api ruby client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)! and want to limit the request to online access. I expected that to be the default but the app always tells the user that it will "Perform these operations when I'm not using the application" and in the url it says "oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=..."

All I want is the users email ("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"). Is it possible to ask for it without asking for offline access?

Answer (score 2):

When you generate the `authorization_uri`, pass an `:access_type` parameter set to `:online`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do it.

Comment: `client.authorization.authorization_uri(:access_type => :online)`